# Stuck at on_member_join event. (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so im making a welcomer script for my community server. Actually theres no errors in console, its just simply doesnt work. How could i fix it?

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Unverified")
    await member.add_roles(role)

    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome")
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome {member}", color=discord.Colour.blue())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

> Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Zsombor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get a `Context` parameter for the `on_member_join` event, only a `Member` parameter. Therefore, you'll need to access the `Guild` in some other way.

Fortunately, this can easily be done; `Member` objects have a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.Member.guild) attribute.

You can also simplify grabbing the Unverified role and welcome channel by using [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get). So, with those changes:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Unverified")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="welcome")
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome {member}", color=discord.Colour.blue())
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: No errors, but still not working. Neither the welcome msg or the autorole.

Comment: Is this in a *properly loaded* cog/properly setup extension? Are there any logs in the console or logfile at all?

Comment: It loads every cog without error, nothing else.

Comment: Are you able to step through with a debugger and see if the function gets called at all? Are you sure that the *cog* is being added properly and not just the extension being loaded (assuming you're using extensions)? Also, importantly, make sure you have the members intent enabled in the developer portal **and** in your `Bot.intents`.

Comment: Intents are enabled. I ran a debugger, but it found nothing and i dont see anything which would suggest that the cog is not being added..

Comment: Just to check, are you sure you enabled the members intent in your `Intents` object in your code (as well as the dev portal)? It is disabled by default, so that would be the issue if you did not explicitly enable it.

Comment: Yes it is enabled in the code and in the dev portal too, i checked it twice.

Comment: Would you like to see the whole code?

Comment: I edited my question because now theres an error in console. Check it now.

Comment: Why did you remove the self parameter from your function definition?

Comment: Its there, donno why i removed here..